# Webpack. Is it possible to make entry-point dependent import?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I have application with multiple entry points, bundled by webpack 1.13.2. I am also using ES2015 modules and babel with es-2015 preset.

```
entry: {
        entry1: "app/somechunk/entry1.js",
        entry2: "app/somechunk2/entry2.js"
}
```

And I want conditional imports for particular module. Import should depend on entry point. Something like this:

```
if(entry1){
    import locale from 'app/somechunk/localeDictionary1.js'
} else {
    import locale from 'app/somechunk2/localeDictionary2.js'
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but entry files are already isolated, they are separate files after all. In each individual entry just import the specific file you want, there is no need for an if condition.

Comment: @MarcGreenstock. I have let's say translator.js and multiple localization dictionaries. I need translator.js for every entry point. And I want to import localization dictionary conditionally depending of entry point.

Comment: Translator is useless without dictionary, so I can import dictionary with my translator in every file where I trying to use translator. (2 imports for each module). There are a lot of modules, it will be painful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's a question that comes up quite often. You cannot have conditional imports in javascript, dependencies are static properties of the modules. You have basically two options:

## Object-oriented solution using [dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

Use a common module and provide a configurator function for it. For example:

```
// locale.js
export var dictionary = {};
export function setDictionary(dict) {
  dictionary = dict;
}

// locale-en.js
import { setDictionary } from "./locale";
setDictionary({ yes: "yes" });

// locale-hu.js
import { setDictionary } from "./locale";
setDictionary({ yes: "igen" });

// entries/entry-hu.js
import "../locales/locale-hu";
import "../application";

// entries/entry-en.js
import "../locales/locale-en";
import "../application";

// application.js
import { dictionary } from "./locales/locale";
console.log(dictionary);
```

## Static config using [aliases](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias)

Configure separate build tasks for the entries, and configure them with:

```
{
    entry: "entry.js",
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "locale": "/locale/locale-en.js"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```